Creating an image view with "bite mark" shaped corner
I created a custom image view which applies a rectangle shape where the bottom corners remain untouched, the upper left corner is rounded and the upper right corner is curved inward. All of this works by drawing this path in code.
The end product should look like someone took a bite out of this corner so that you have teeth marks.
class ClipPathImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context,
attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

private val path = Path()

override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

    path.reset()

    val cornerRadius = 50f
    val cutoutRadius = 100f
    val cutoutWidth = cutoutRadius
    val cutoutHeight = cutoutRadius

    val padding = 0f
    val pathLeft = padding
    val pathRight = width - padding
    val pathTop = padding
    val pathBottom = height.toFloat() - padding

    val cutoutXStart = width / 2 - cutoutWidth
    val cutoutXEnd = cutoutXStart + cutoutWidth * 2
    val topCutoutYStart = pathTop - cutoutHeight
    val topCutoutYEnd = pathTop + cutoutHeight 

    path.moveTo(pathLeft + cornerRadius, pathTop)

    path.lineTo(cutoutXStart, pathTop)

    path.arcTo(RectF(cutoutXStart + w/2, topCutoutYStart, cutoutXEnd + w/2, topCutoutYEnd), 180f, -90f)

    path.lineTo(pathRight, pathBottom)

    path.lineTo(pathRight, pathBottom)

    path.lineTo(pathLeft, pathBottom)

    path.lineTo(pathLeft, pathBottom)

    path.lineTo(pathLeft, pathTop + cornerRadius)

    path.arcTo(RectF(pathLeft, pathTop, pathLeft + cornerRadius * 2, pathTop + cornerRadius * 2), 180f, 90f)

    path.close()
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {

    canvas.save()
    canvas.clipPath(path)
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas.restore()
}
}

The code above is what I currently have.
And this is the shape:

With bite shape i mean something like this:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
